# VBA generated output: only data that satisfies certain criteria in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a model that currently looks like this - input sheet --> basic excel functions --> output sheet. Basic stuff right?!

I want to make the model more dynamic by adding a VBA generated output (New Sheet), only pulling the data that satisfies certain criteria based on the following:

```
Sub GenerateTargets()
'Dim UpperRange As Double
'Dim LowerRange As Double
'Dim Percentile As Double
'Dim Test
'Dim Total Revenue {Note: [This is a header in the output sheet] [should I use Array or Range? If array is it Stat or Dynamic] I might change the input later on and increase the number of observations}


'Read Values in Cells
UpperRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value
LowerRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value

Test = UpperRange > Percentile > LowerRange

Case Test Is True
    [This is the test I want to generate]

Case Test Is False
    [I do not want this to show in my new sheet]

[Here I would like to add another Case to stop counting if [Total revenue = ##]

End Sub
```

How do I ask it to generate the same headers/Data in the output but eliminating the false case, in the same time stop counting if it reaches a certain threshold.

Would appreciate any help/suggestions --

Comment: Please provide more info about the input and output sheets (provide and example).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then see this code. You don't need a Select Case since you want to execute the code only when "TEST" is TRUE. You can check for "REVENUE" condition inside the FOR Loop. You ca use a dynamic array to store your values and then write to the OUTPUT sheet in the end.

```
Sub GenerateTargets()
    Dim UpperRange As Double, LowerRange As Double, Percentile As Double
    Dim Rev As Double
    Dim Test As Boolean
    Dim Output() As String

    Rev = Somevalue '<~~ Revenue

    '~~> Read Values in Cells
    UpperRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value
    LowerRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(x, y).Value

    '~~> Test Condition
    'Test = UpperRange > Percentile > LowerRange

    If Test = True Then
        '~~> Use For Loop here to store values in a dynamic array
        '~~> Use Redim Preserve to store new values

        '~~> Create a condition for revenue and exit FOR loop if
        '~~> the condition is met
        ' If Rev = 0 Then Exit For

        '~~> Store results in the output worksheet if the array is not empty
    End If
End Sub
```

***FOLLOW UP***

Is this what you are trying to do? (CODE IS UNTESTED in the absence of sample file). I have commented the code so that you will have no problems in understanding the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateTargets()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim UpperRange As Double, LowerRange As Double, Percentile As Double
    Dim lastRowWs1 As Long, lastRowWs2 As Long, i as Long

    '~~> Sheet where data needs to be copied
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRowWs1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Sheet where the data needs to be compared
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    '~~> Read Values in Cells
    UpperRange = ws2.Range("L2").Value
    LowerRange = ws2.Range("L3").Value
    lastRowWs2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Starting from the 3rd row
    For i = 3 To lastRowWs2
        '~~> Get Percentile Value for comparision
        Percentile = ws2.Range("B" & i).Value

        '~~> Test Condition and proceed if true
        If UpperRange > Percentile And LowerRange < Percentile Then
            '~~> Copy range A to I from Sheet2 and paste it in Sheet1
            ws2.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Copy _
            ws1.Range("A" & lastRowWs1)
            lastRowWs1 = lastRowWs1 + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, whats the syntax for the loop? How can I get it to store the whole array but only test one column. Also, how do i feed the results into a new sheet? By the way i decided against adding a rev test.

Comment: @user1207643: Wow so many questions :). Would it be possible for you upload few snapshots on how your input and output sheet looks like? That ways, I can get my references correct while answering your questions.

Comment: Of course! Sorry if my questions are overwhelming - I want to output the same data but based on the Test and rev count in a new sheet!

Comment: http://i1260.photobucket.com/albums/ii569/ialgannas/ScreenShot2012-02-15at53822PM.png